# How to keep Dropbox sync api pathListener registered after phone reboots or sleeps

Tags: android, dropbox, synchronization, dropbox-api

I have an app listening for changes in a Dropbox account using the Sync API. I have registered the path listener using DbxFileSystem.addPathListener() and I create an Android notification when onPathChange() is triggered. This works well while the app is on the screen and when the app is closed and other apps are running. It also works if I lock my device and the screen is off. However after a while (I assume when the phone goes into sleep mode) or when the device is rebooted the listener seems to not be registered anymore. If I then go into my app a notfication will be sent of changes that have occured in the folder, so the listener is re-registered again.

I am hoping someone could provide a clear direction of how to keep the listener registered "all the time". I have done some googling about services and broadcastReceivers but I haven't been able to work out the answer

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure off hand if there's a way to have this registered all the time, but it sounds like the issue here is due to how Android handles the lifecycle of apps. In any case though, it's probably worth mentioning that this is actually not recommended, per the very bottom of https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android#listeners .

Comment: Thanks Greg. Yes I had seen at the bottom of the sync api tutorial that this was not recommended, however do other apps not do this kind of  polling/listening in the background e.g. apps like twitter that notify when there has been a retweet etc. or whatsapp notifying that there is a new message? This is the kind of functionality I am trying to have with changes to a Dropbox folder. I may have to have a look at the Dropbox core api and see what that provides.